# ASP.NET HttpModule gives “Connection Reset” in browser

Tags: iis, http, httpmodule

I have implemented a HttpModule in ASP.NET (framework 2.0).

From my logging on the server, I can see that the http request is being picked up by my HttpModule, and my code runs successfully (writing content back to the Response stream).

However, the web browser (IE, FF, Chrome, all the same) just give me a "connection reset" error message.

I've checked the Event Log on the server; there are no related errors or messages there.

When I use the "Live HTTP Headers" plugin in FF, it does not even display my client request (although I am sure it reaches the server, due to the request being captured in the server log).

How can I troubleshoot what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question at StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574451/asp-net-httpmodule-gives-connection-reset-in-browser

Sorry for the cross-posting.

Answer (score 0):

Use "http interceptor". There are many. One can easily find on internet.

It seems that everybody uses [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) except me.  I would prefer you make your choice

BTW, write versions and editions of browsers. Start describing your situation in context of one chosen IE, since it is from the same MS (but note there are buggy differences between them)